# VNC in reverse Direction

Tags: vnc, rdp

I am developing a Remote Desktop application Like Tight VNC
But the Problem is the end that broadcasts the Screenshots doesn't have a Public IP
However the recieving end have.I was planing to use TightVNC Source Code. So is it feasible to use TightVNC Source for this purpouse as I dont see any such option in Tight VNC where the Sending end doesn't have Public 
IP.

Comment: You will likely need to develop an inside-out connection (where the remote host initiates the connection based on a control server, kind of like GoToMyPC does).

Comment: What libs can I use for this purpose ? or I've to do it from the scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC allows for the Viewer / Client to start in "Listen-Mode" and wait for a server to connect. This is the reverse connection you speak of. Some tools provide a VNC Server contained in a Windows Exe that connects to a definded Viewer on startup, it allows Remote Support behind a home router. See the [docs](http://www.tightvnc.com/winst.php) for more Infos (look for "Add new client" on Server Tray Icon)

Clarification:

When I want to use Tight VNC to Remote your PC (See your Desktop), I would normally do:

Connect my Client to your Server on your Public IP

Reverse VNC:

You Add my Public IP to your Server wich connects to my Client

Comment: Yes But it needs the Client to be identifiable. e.g. When you `Add new Client` it asks for Client's IP. here In My case the Client doesn't have an Public IP.

Comment: The "Client" would be the one with the Public IP and will view the Screen of the Server. In this scenario "Client" and "Server" are easy to mix up : (